# Use locate (or find) command to locate files on Windows partition from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, find, locate

I use the `locate` command quite heavily to search for files on my system and I think it works quite well for me.

I am now on a system with a double partition (Windows and Ubuntu) and I would like also to be able to `locate` files on my Windows partition.

I tried to do

`sudo updatedb`

`locate FILETOBEFOUND`

but it does not work. Do you know if there is a way to make it work? Is maybe the `find` command a better option for what I want to do. I tried that too but without success.

EDIT: the windows partition is NTFS and I can access it from the file explorer

Comment: First what is the file system of the Windows part? Can you access the Windows part with the file manager? What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you mounted the Windows partition?

Comment: Check `/etc/updatedb.conf` if the file system, the windows partition is mounted with is in `PRUNEFS` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited my question: I am able to access my Windows NTFS partition.

Comment: ... Windows partitions are often user-mounted in `/media` in which case `PRUNEPATHS` may be a factor here as well

Comment: I can access my partition in the `/media` folder (more specifically `/media/USERNAME/Windows/` and I checked the PRUNEPATHS which indeed contains the `/media` folder but I still cannot locate the files on the Windows Partition. I even tried to put the folder `/media/schianof/Windows/`in the PRUNEPATHS variable without success.

Comment: @desmond13 you would need to *remove* `/media` from `PRUNEPATHS` (and re-run `sudo updatedb`)

Comment: LOL, sorry, I meant that I removed it. But forgot to run `sudo updatedb`

Comment: It works now after doing `sudo updatedb`